# Overlapping Questions

Tags: support, allowed-topics, asking-questions, stackexchange

Certain logical questions belong as well in Philosophy Stack Exchange as they do in Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For example [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/is-it-possible-to-generate-logically-valid-sentences-made-up-of-atomic-contradi/1189#1189) and [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/why-is-this-set-cqcpq-ccpcqrccpqcpr-ccnpnqcqp-the-most-common-set-of-axioms) both fall within the purview of both stackexchanges.  But, the people who will read Philosophy Stack Exchange are by no means the same as those who read Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Does there exist a way to make it so that questions can appear on both Stack Exchanges?  If not, can that get done?  If neither of those can get done, how does one communicate the question to both sets of people?

Comment: In general, the different StackExchange sites try not to have multiple posts or overlapping questions. I do see that these questions relate to both math and philosophy, but the characters of these two exchanges are very different from each other. I believe that every question should be asked in a place where it is more likely to get the better (and more intended) answer. And if that fails, then we can migrate it or the OP can cross-post it

Comment: If these questions are different (they seem to be now, but I'm no math whiz), they can both be open and posted on whichever site. If they are the same question, but worded differently (tailored to each site), then [it's still OK](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931/cross-posting-on-stackexchange-sites). But one should only be closed if they are exact duplicates.

Comment: @stoicfury Will you please vote to reopen this then http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/why-is-this-set-cqcpq-ccpcqrccpqcpr-ccnpnqcqp-the-most-common-set-of-axioms?

Comment: Just to summarize: it appears the consensus reached here is that these are duplicates and not tailored for philosophy.se -- @stoicfury please let me know if you feel differently about these?

Comment: In passing if you would unpack or develop the question a bit more and try to identify the specifically philosophical concern I will certainly reconsider my close vote.

Comment: @JosephWeissman As they currently stand (and I intend to keep them this way), the math question asks a question about a 9 letter axiom which given conditional proof, conditional elimination, and substitution comes as sufficient for all of propositional calculus.  The philosophy question asks about the commonality of the axiom set {CqCpq, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCNpNqCqp}.  The consensus reached concerned earlier versions of the questions.  Stoicfury no doubt has seen this.

Answer (score 5):

Cross-posting is an issue that has been addressed on stackoverflow:

- [cross posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931/cross-posting-on-stackexchange-sites)
- [c-p etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette)
- [c-p rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87739/clarification-regarding-cross-posting-rules)
- [c-p faux pas](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/610/cross-posting-on-different-se-sites-faux-pas)

To summarize,

- cross-posting (having an identical question, either by copy/paste or by an implemented mechanism in the system) is **strongly** discouraged (and a feature to implement it has been stated will not happen).
- it is not a terrible thing to 're-ask' a question, specifically tailored to each site ("each site is autonomous"), but it is discouraged.
- if your question turns out to just not be appropriate to the site you are posting too or is not getting the expected answers, there is a mechanism to move a question to another site (flag to a moderator and they can 'reassign' the question).

Comment: But what if the question doesn't need any tailoring?  In other words, what if it comes as appropriate to ask it in the exact same way on both sites?

Comment: @Doug: I'm just reporting what I read (that cut and paste is not wanted). I'd say work with the spirit of the rule, tailor as mich as is needed, but you'll have to judge for yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  The comments here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73184/why-is-cqcpq-ccpcqrccpqcpr-ccnpnqcqp-the-most-common-axiomization-of-proposi perhaps might indicate tailoring  as possibly contentious to some.

Comment: @Doug: Wow... my multiple comments: that question sure generated a lot o comments, 2) and it seems I must have been too weak in my answer here, and 3) principle is not the same as execution (meaning, you may have thought you tailored but they didn't).

Comment: @Doug: Oh and it is my opinion that both questions would have been better suited and better answered from the beginning at math.SE, because they are involve a lot of mathematical judgement (despite the technical overlap between the two domains on this question).

Comment: You weren't necessarily too weak.  Some questions might get really tricky to tailor.  It does seem at least possible that some question can get written which needs absolutely no, nada, zero, tailoring between stackexchanges.  What does do with overlaps in the case of such a question?  At the time I posted it, I couldn't ask it on math.stackexchange.  But, I do think that philosophically-inclined people might have as interesting of answers as mathematically-inclined people to such a question.